# X,Y position percent to degrees?

Tags: analysis

My english its not that good so im going to explain with picture.

[image]

So the first circle is the info I can get, x % and y %, what I want to know its the degrees of the red dot. The second picture shows what I want. Can I some how use x% and y% to know the degrees of the red dot?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @almagest thank you but to be honest I dont know what $\tan means. Can you write it in another way? so i can implement it in the java program

Comment: The tangent of an angle is the opposite side divided by the adjacent side in a right-angled triangle. There is a function for it in every programming language. If the angle is $\theta$ you have $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}$. Fortunately there is a standard inverse function often called "arctan" which gives you $\theta=$ arctan $\frac{y}{x}$. That is also implemented in most programming languages. I am afraid I don't use Java.

Comment: okay I found a function call Math.tan() and it takes up a angle in radians as parameters, and "returns the trigonometric tangent of an angle". but I do not have the angle in radians. @almagest

Comment: $180^o=\pi$ radians, where $\pi=$3.141592653589793. Math.tan() sounds like tan. You want the inverse function. Probably atan().

Comment: Math.atan() Returns the arc tangent of a value; the returned angle is in the range, which should I use atan() or tan()? xd

Comment: okay okay. let me se if i get this right. Thanks will be back soon :)

Comment: $atan$. But do a few tests. You have $45^o=$0.785398 radians and $\tan45^o=1$. So atan(1) should return 0.785398.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up Unit Circle definition of trigonometric functions.

Generally, in coordinate geometry, we measure angle from positive $X$ axis and in anti-clockwise sense. In your figure, you are measuring the angle from $Y$ axis, and in clockwise sense. So we have

[image]

$$\tan \alpha = \dfrac{x}{y}\\
\alpha = \arctan \left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)$$

So feed this value into your **atan** function, and multiply it by $\dfrac{180}{\pi}$

Comment: Im sorry I know its me, but what should i feed my atan function? Math.atan(xPercent/yPercent)?

Comment: Yes probably. If you are measuring the angle the way you showed in the image.

Comment: okay so I did this `float degrees = (float)(Math.atan(x/y)*180/3.14f);` and it measure good until the red dot  pass 90 degrees(or X is negative). then it goes from 90 to -89.